How to extract particular field from custom duplicate objects and build a another response list using java 8 streams
I have below response from database and I need to convert it into the final json format using java 8 streams.
Response from Database:
[
{
"name": "Test1",
"age": "33",
"city": "City1",
"status": "Insert"
},
{
"name": "Test1",
"age": "33",
"city": "City1",
"status": "Update"
},
{
"name": "Test1",
"age": "33",
"city": "City1",
"status": "Delete"
}
]
Final Response:
{
"name": "Test1",
"age": "33",
"city": "Chennai",
"status": [
"Insert",
"Update",
"Delete"
]
}

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
